# Scrapy spider cannot crawl a url but scrapy shell does it successfully

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, craigslist

I am trying to scrape craiglist. When I try to fetch  https://tampa.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=bookkeeper in the spider I am getting the following error:

*(extra newlines and white space added for readability)*

```
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG:
    Retrying <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=bookkeeper> (failed 1 times):
    [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost:
    Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

But, when I try to crawl it on scrapy shell, it is being crawled successfully.

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
    Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=bookkeeper>
    (referer: None)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I have tried forcing TLSv1.2 but had no luck. I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: The thing with Scrapy Shell is that it uses the settings from the project it's been run from, which is very convenient. However, if you have some settings in your project which make the spider not work, AND if you ran the shell from some other folder, this would explain the behavior. That's the best I can do without any code :)

Comment: That might be the case, I am using a long sleep time in the script, might be the reason behind it. what do you think? @bosnjak

Comment: I am sorry but I can't post the full code. Do you think the long sleep time causing the problem? @ck-chen

Comment: @ArindamGhosh using sleep inside Scrapy sounds like a problem to me. Scrapy is using twisted to run asynchronously, and using sleep should never be an option. If you can provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I could help, otherwise I'm not sure how.

Comment: @bosnjak here is a snippet of the code `sleep(random.randrange(5,10))
                    yield Request(url, callback=self.fetch_url) ` 
because of the blocking, I was using a long sleep time before making new requests.` fetch_url  ` function fetches all the post links present in the page and calls another function to extract details from the posts.

Comment: @ArindamGhosh sorry but that's not enough for me to help, read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here, check the craiglist.py script. [link](https://github.com/rearindam/craiglist-scraper) @bosnjak

Comment: @ArindamGhosh check out my answer below please.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the comments, which means you should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. 
To help you out, this is what it's all about:

```
import scrapy


class CLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'CL Spider'
    start_urls = ['https://tampa.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=bookkeeper']

    def parse(self, response):
            for url in response.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # TODO: scrape item details here
        return {
            'url': response.url,
            # ...
            # ...
        }
```

Now, this MCVE does everything you want to do in a nutshell:

- visits one of the search pages
- iterates through the results
- visits each item for parsing

This should be your starting point for debugging, removing all the unrelated boilerplate.

Please test the above and verify if it's working? If it works, add more functionality in steps so you can figure out which part introduces the problem. If it doesn't work, don't add anything else until you can figure out why.

**UPDATE:**

Adding a delay between requests can be done in two ways:

1. Globally for all spiders in `settings.py` by specifying for example `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2` for a 2 second delay between each download.
2. Per-spider by defining an attribute `download_delay`,

for example:

```
class CLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'CL Spider'
    download_delay = 2
```

Documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay

Comment: I want to add delays to each request so that it seems more human to to the website. If you can tell me the best way to do that that would be very helpful. @bosnjak